# Binomial Probability Question - Capacity of a River Ferry

Tags: probability

> A particular river ferry has $85$ seats, however, the booking company always takes $90$ bookings knowing that $0.10$ of people will not show up to the ferry before it leaves. Find an expression for the probability that the boat will not have enough seats. Assume each passenger acts independently.

The solution I have is,

Let $X$ denote "the number of passengers who do not show up out of $90$."

$\begin{align}Pr(X \leq 5) &= {90 \choose 0}(0.10)^0(0.90)^{90} + {90 \choose 1}(0.10)^1(0.90)^{89} + {90 \choose 2}(0.10)^2(0.90)^{88} + {90 \choose 3}(0.10)^3(0.90)^{87} + {90 \choose 4}(0.10)^4(0.90)^{86} + {90 \choose 5}(0.10)^5(0.90)^{85} \\&=\sum^{5}_{x =0}{90 \choose x}(0.10)^x(0.90)^{90-x}\\& \end{align}$

However, the solution in the book reads,

$$Pr ( X \leq 4) = \sum^{4}_{x =0}{90 \choose x}(0.10)^x(0.90)^{90-x}$$

Why do they not consider $x = 5$ as well, like I have?

Comment: If $X=5$ then the boat will have enough seats.

Comment: Wow, of course, thanks NCh.

Comment: @NCh Perhaps you could expand that into an answer.

Comment: @IanMiller No, thank you. It is extremly simple.